# How to initiallize values in a redux form using mapStateToProps from a custom JSON as prop?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am building a redux form  where i want to get initialValues passed via props which are present in a different JSON Object.

The structure of the JSON Object that I am passing as Props is:-

```
"Team": {
      "Manager": {
           "name": "Tom"
      },
      "members": {
        "PD" : {
          "SE": {
            "name" : "SAM"
          }
        }
      }
 },
```

My redux forms havs 2 fields where I need to populate the initial state as Tom and SAM

I am calling the class that has the redux-form like this:-

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}><Emp empJSON={}/></Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#tenant-content')
);
```

The Emp class is like this:-

```
Emp.propTypes = {
    empJSON: PropTypes.object,

};

Emp.defaultProps ={
    empJSON:{},
}



export default reduxForm({
    form: 'empForm', // a unique identifier for this form
    onSubmit: submit,

},mapStateToProps )(Emp);

renderPartnerName.propTypes  = {
    input: PropTypes.object,
};
```

I also have a function

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    // state will be the state of your redux store
    // ownProps will be your component's props
    console.log(state)
    console.log(ownProps)

    return {
        initialValues: {
            EmployeeName: ownProps.members.PD.SE.name,
        }

}}
```

However nothing is printed on the console nor is the initialvalues set.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to pass `mapStateToProps` directly to redux-form like that -- are you missing `connect`?

```
Emp = connect(mapStateToProps)(Emp);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'empForm', // a unique identifier for this form
    onSubmit: submit,

})(Emp);
```

See http://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/

Comment: Oh I followed this git hub post to do this.https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/916I shall try this out